# how can i change focus from one object to next preferred focus view which i want in appleTv os development project in swift3

Tags: swift3, apple-tv, tvos9.1

Actually i'm developing a **Apple Tv** project in swift3.I faced some problem with focus navigation using remote. 
Is there any way to change focus from one object to another object which i want.

I tried below code but **not working**......

```
override var preferredFocusedView: UIView? {
    get {
        return preferredFocusedView1
        }
}
```

[In the bellow screenshot i want to move focus from the pink icon to the star button when pressed down button of remote. how it is possible. plz provide me some code in details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AGcWs.jpg)